# multiple errors, not redirecting, apache2/htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^. /archive/index.php [L]
```

going to domain.com will redirect me to www.domain.com

however, going to domain.com/2011/11/18/blog-title will show http://domain.com/var/htdocs/public_html/ instead in the browser URL.

My objective is any page at domain.com will redirect to www.domain.com

and wether I go to www.domain.com or domain.com /YYYY or /YYYY/MM or /YYYY/MM/DD will pass a PHP REQUEST_URI so I can get data from a MySQL database.

I originally copied the .htaccess file from WordPress but it doesn't seem to work properly since /var/htdocs/public_html appears in the browser URL bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or this if you want a specific domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The rules are from Drupal 7 and Drupal 6 respectively and have always worked well for me

**EDIT**

Looking at your code again I think the only problem is that you don't have a `/` between `http://www.domain.com` and `$1`. Other than that it's pretty much identical to the second example above which definitely works

Comment: Here is what I get when going to domain.com/2011/11/18/      http://search3.comcast.com/?cat=dnsr&con=ds&url=www.domain.comvar

Comment: I think the problem is your second rewrite rule then because both of the above rules work perfectly for many thousands of sites :). Try copying the second rule exactly as is from the Wordpress `.htaccess` file again and see if you get any joy

Comment: I got it working. I think the browser cached the old .htaccess.